# Where are you from? Singular or plural

Tags: sentence-meaning

We say "where are you from?" To someone or one person  to ask about where they live but if we have to ask to a group of people or more than one or two people do we ask in same way? (Where are you from? )

Answer (score 1):

The singular and plural pronoun in English is: you. We might say: Where are all of you from? For a group. Or: Where is each of you from?

That way a group of people understands the question is directed at each of them.